# Spring Boot - How to transfer files between user accounts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file

I have a way of uploading files to a database and then downloading them from the database (JPA).

But how would I go about allowing users to transfer a file to another user account?

Comment: How are the files tied to the user account? Do you have some mapping tables mapping from file id to user id?

Comment: @dunni Oh I see I didn't think about that. Now I know how to map a database table to an entity class, but I don't know how I would go about mapping from file id to user id. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: It depends a little bit on your existing datamodel. You should add to your question, what you already have.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.